# Logging in the winform application using AOP and proxies

Tags: c#, .net, logging, unity-container, aop

Let's move to details.

For example I have a class and logic named `ImportAction`. This class has some public and private methods. I invoke some methods. In these methods I instantiate other classes (skip DI comments please, it's legacy :) and invoke some methods of them (and so on). Also I have several private fields in both classes, and some returning values from the invocation.

I need to log all specific values I'll choose from all participants.

I read about AOP and want to use **Unity Interception** to catch invocation. But I don't know is it possible to get private state of the method / class.

I understand that I need proxy for all used types during my ImportAction execution. Bu also I need their private fields and return values.

Is it good approach to implement this? Maybe It's impossible with unity proxies?
All ideas are welcome.

Comment: I don't know what you can do for private members, but you can use Unity if you want to log before/after method calls and any parameters passed.

Answer (score 0):

Unity will not directly give you any ability to access private state (other than by reflection).

However, there are more questions. Strictly speaking you can not use a proxy if you create class directly using `new`. You can manually change the code to create a proxy, but if you do that, why not just log the required information instead? Especially considering that need for private state seems to imply logging is tightly coupled with these classes anyway.

However, if you specifically want to separate logging code from classes using AOP, then you still should be able to do that using some alternative AOP approaches related to code/IL rewriting, for example [`Afterthought`](https://github.com/vc3/Afterthought), `PostSharp` or manual processing with `NRefactory` or similar thing.

Comment: I don't want write throughout the code something like `_logger.log("message", typeOfMessage)`. That's why I need more elegant solution.